# how to add a json file as a resource in reactjs with url?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have added a json file inside the public folder of my react app. When I run npm run build, I can see the file in build folder. But when I deploy the app and try to access the json file by the url: www.myapp.com/jsonResource, I get 404 not found.

I have tried setting homepage:"hostname" in package.json as it was suggested in a few docs. But no luck.

Please help.

Comment: have you tried with .json extension ?

Comment: You should describe _how_ exactly you are deploying your app.

Comment: I am deploying to an Azure resource. Is there any chance of modifying build.js to solve this problem?